# Is it possible to use Break to jump out of or skip crawling function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, web-scraping, web-crawler

Hi i would like to know if it is possible use "break" or any other method to skip the crawling function after running the script for the first time and just use the array variable that contains the crawling information for the next user request.

```
let glossary = [];  

/** Initialise crawling and save it into glossary array */
function init() {
    const glossary_url = 'https://xxxx';

     const headers = {
         cookie: 'cookies:kdkjslkd424'  
     };

    const options = {
        url: glossary_url,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        const newDom = new jsdom(body);
        const $ = require('jquery')(newDom.window);

        $('ul > li > span[style="line-height:1.6;"]').each(function (index, element) {
            let text = element.textContent.trim(); // Get text from html
            let splitText = text.split(' = '); // split text by =
            //console.log(text);


            if (splitText.length > 1) {
                glossary.push({
                    key: splitText[0].trim(),
                    value: splitText[1],
                    value2: splitText[2]
                });
            }
        });
        //console.log(glossary);

        findMatch('DPDL');
    });
}
 break init;

function findMatch (key){
    for(i = 0; i < glossary.length ; i++) {
        if (glossary[i].key === key){
            // console.log (glossary[i].value );
            // console.log(glossary[i].key);
            // console.log(glossary[i].value2);
            // console.log(key);
            console.log(key + ' = ' + glossary[i].value + ' ' + glossary[i].value2 );
        } 
    } 

}


init();
```

break or skip the crawl function if user wants to search another value it will just find in the glossary array *glossary = []* and not crawl again as it takes long time

Comment: `break init` ... is not valid - see [documentation for break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) - you can "break" to a "label" - but, since `init` is only called once, I can't see what your problem is

Comment: @JaromandaX what im trying to do is to take the user input value multiple times and search the value  in the   glossary array so it will be faster to give the result rather than to have crawl the page each time user want to find a new value/input....